# Align img to bottom of relative divs

Tags: html, css, image

I have a table with a fixed height (500px) but relative width (100% of screen). The table is serving as a size comparison chart, with a grid for a background image with units of measurment along the left edge.

The table consists of three cells: a blank one to hold the empty space for the legend along the left edge, a middle cell that displays the page's item and a right cell that is populated with an image of another item the user wants to compare sizes to.

I can get this to display relatively well but the caveat is that the images are aligning themselves tot he top edge of the table rather than the bottom edges.

Any attempt I make at modifying the position and display settings only make the images disappear from view.

HTML:

```
<div id="scalechart">
        <div id="buffer"></div>
        <div id="nochoice"><img src="http://www.example.com/image1.png" class="leader"></div>
        <div id="firstchoice"><img src="http://www.example.com/image2.png" class="leader"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
scalechart {
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    height: 500px;
    clear: both;
    background: url(../../legend.png) no-repeat, url(../../Gridlines.png) repeat-x;
    background-size: contain;
}

#buffer {
    width: 144px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#nochoice, #firstchoice {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

I've tried making the positions absolute and setting the bottom and left to 0 but the images just disappear. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you talk about table but use float, why not display:table/table-cell ?

i removed some css i thought useless here for the demo.

```css
#scalechart {
  text-align: right;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  height: 500px;
  background: url(../../legend.png) no-repeat, url(../../Gridlines.png) repeat-x;
  background-size: contain;
}
#buffer {
  width: 144px;
  display: table-cell;
}
#nochoice,
#firstchoice {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="scalechart">
  <div id="buffer"></div>
  <div id="nochoice">
    <img src="http://www.example.com/image1.png" class="leader">
  </div>
  <div id="firstchoice">
    <img src="http://www.example.com/image2.png" class="leader">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This did the trick, but now I wonder how I can make it so that on mobile devices, the table doesn't squish the images but overlays them (if it has no choice).